# How can I get the boost numeric bindings?

Tags: c++, boost, numeric

I have a file that needs to use boost numeric bindings's library. How can I get that binding library?

The following link seems not able to work anymore. The zipped file is corrupted.
http://mathema.tician.de/dl/software/boost-numeric-bindings/

And I hope I could use it in Window and Visual Studio tool.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a file that needs to use boost numeric bindings's library. How can I get that binding library?

You can grab the sources of the current version via
`svn co http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/numeric_bindings`

The version from http://mathema.tician.de/dl/software/boost-numeric-bindings/ is an older version with a different interface. You can grab the sources of that older version via
`svn co http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/numeric_bindings-v1`

> And I hope I could use it in Window and Visual Studio tool.

You need a blas/lapack library in addition to the bindings. For windows, Intel MKL, AMD's ACML, clapack and atlas used to work, last time I checked. (You only need one of these, but note that atlas only implements blas and a small subset of lapack). These libraries have widely different performance and license conditions, but they all implement the same interface (more or less).

In general, the people at http://lists.boost.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/ublas seem to be helpful, if you try to use the bindings (or ublas) and run into problems. But I'm not sure if any of them checks here at stackoverflow for potential users that ran into problems.